# Android Camera App with multiple images in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, camera, position, imageview, selected

I'm working on a camera app which displays more than one image dynamically added to a simple LinearLayout as childs. When a specefic image is selected (onClick), it goes to Camera View (camera Intent). The App is supposed to display the new image captured in the right selected ImageView. The thing is, I don't know how to get that specific ImageView to handle it in onActivityResult method. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In your `onActivityResult()`

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (data != null) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
}
```

Where `data` is the intent.

You can just save the clicked `ImageView`'s reference before you open the Camera app, and use that reference to set the new image.

**Update:** Just make an `ImageView` variable in your activity, and before you open the Camera, put the clicked instance in this field, and use this `ImageView` in my example code.

Comment: Thank you very much paradax for your response. About the ImageView's reference, can you please give me some implementation elements to start with ?